# When one merges accounts, contacts or leads what happens to lookup relationships?

Tags: account, leads, contact, merge

I imagine if the lookup relationship points to the merge winner, then nothing changes, but what happens if the lookup points to the merge loser? Does the lookup afterwards get automatically updated to point to the winner, or is it necessary to write a trigger to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_merge.htm), they will move:

> Any related items from any of the duplicate accounts will be associated with the newly merged account.